# Download coordinate file from a map-based website

Tags: google-maps, kml, map-service

I want ask is it possible for me to download the location detail (coordinate and location's name) of a map-based website?

I'm trying to get all the ports name and location from one of these websites

```
http://www.worldportsource.com/ports/TWN.php
```

or

```
https://www.searates.com/maritime/taiwan
```

if you open the website you can see there are some ports and I want to get all the name and its coordinate, in .kml format file, if possible.

Do you have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the data is stored in an object called `jPortData`. So what you can do is write some code in the Javascript Console (e.g.: in [Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/javascript/)).

Run this code:

```javascript
// Create root geojson FeatureCollection
const root = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": []
}

// Loop the port data and create a geojson feature for each port
jPortData.forEach((portData) => {
    root.features.push({
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": portData.id,
      "properties": {
        ...portData
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          parseFloat(portData.lng),
          parseFloat(portData.lat)
        ]
      }
    });
});

// Log the result stringified to the console
console.log(JSON.stringify(root,null,2));
```

So now we have your data as `geojson`. You could now save the result in a text file and open it in QGIS and convert it to `KML`. Another option would be to copy the result to [geojson.io](https://geojson.io/). There you can also export your data as `KML`.

[image: Geojson.io Result]

You can directly copy the output to your clipboard in Chrome using the `copy` function.

```javascript
// Copy to clipboard
copy(JSON.stringify(root,null,2));
```

Comment: hi @bloigge and polygeo thank you for you help. you help me save a lot of time. i hope you have a nice day.

thank you